# IE9 crashes after jquery click event

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I am having a weird issue with IE9 crashing whenever a click event occurs. I thought it was the clone function maybe a bug with it so tried removing it but same issue. It is working in all browsers even IE7 and 8 but 9 just constantly crashes and not sure.

```
    <div class="icons">
        <span class="attMessage"></span>
        <span class="successMessage"></span>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="newSection">
        <h3>Add/Update Adjuster License</h3>
        <p>(this is where i am appending an icon from above)</p>
        <p><a title="Add license to queue" class="addLicense"></a></p>  
    </div>
```

_

```
    $('.addLicense').click(function () {
      var parent = $(this).parent();
      var license = $('.licenseOverview');
      var dropdown = $('#MainContent_ddlLicenseStates').val();
      var number = $('#MainContent_txtLicenseNumber').val();
      if (number != '') {            
        notifier(parent, "License Added To Queue", "Success");
        $('#MainContent_txtLicenseNumber').val('');
      }
      else {
        notifier(parent, "Must Enter A License Number", "Failure");
      }
    });

    function notifier(oAppend, oMessage, oMessageType) {
      var iconDiv = $('.icons');
      if (oMessageType == 'Success') {
      $('.icons > .successMessage').clone().html(oMessage).appendTo(oAppend).delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).fadeOut();
      //tried a different way since i thought clone was crashing ie9        
      //$('.icons > .successMessage').html(oMessage).appendTo(oAppend).delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).fadeOut();
      setTimeout(function () {    oAppend.find('.successMessage').remove().appendTo(iconDiv); }, 2500);
      }
      else if (oMessageType == 'Failure') {
      $('.icons > .errorMessage').clone().html(oMessage).appendTo(oAppend).delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).fadeOut();
      setTimeout(function () { oAppend.find('.errorMessage').remove() }, 2500);

      }
      else if (oMessageType == 'Warning') {
      $('.icons > .attMessage').clone().html(oMessage).appendTo(oAppend).delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).fadeOut();
      setTimeout(function () { oAppend.find('.attMessage').remove() }, 2500);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Open with FF ... any error in the console?

Comment: Doesn't crash on my IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/xgCgB/

Comment: The problem size does seem to grow at n^2. Maybe you're clicking really fast?

Comment: @briank please.... I edited your question to make the javascript readable. You note the difference in the coloured markup?

Comment: When I click my jsfiddle link (asdfdsasdfdsa) like a maniac my IE9 freezes.

Comment: No errors in firebug or chrome developer tools, it crashes randomly in IE9 and tested on another computer to make sure and same result.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks, I was trying to figure out how to get it to do that with js

Comment: probably crashes due to the amount of timeouts and delays, if you clicked too many times it would probably freeze up. You should clear timeout and delays before executing another

Comment: @Huangism ive tried commenting out my timeout functions and still same result

Comment: @briank how about the delays?

Comment: @Huangism how do you clear delay, i know you can use stop() to clear timeout but i dont think that works with delay?

Comment: @briank there is something that cancels the delays, I saw it in another question but I forgot exactly what it was. i think stop might be it

Comment: So i removed all delays and timeouts and still crashing, guess it eliminates that culprit

Comment: @briank ok so remove one element at a time until it stops crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was the fadeIn().delay(500).fadeOut() was culprit. As soon as the the fadeOut occured IE9 crashed. I removed fadeOut and no crashes occured. Instead of using a delay i used a timeout function to handle the fadeOut and no more crashing.

```
    $('.icons > .successMessage').clone().html(oMessage).appendTo(oAppend).delay(100).fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(function () { oAppend.find('.successMessage').fadeOut().remove(); }, 2500);
```